# Get records equal or bigger and nulled

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm tring to get all records that are bigger than 60 minutes of the current datetime and also with column called `email_sent` of `Null`, but for some reason I'm getting no records when I include the `WHERE email_sent = null`.

If I remove it it works fine. This is strange since all the columns of my records are at `null`. Is my query not well formed?

```
SELECT *
FROM  `claims`
WHERE date_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
  AND email_sent = NULL
```

Comment: Try `email_sent IS NULL`

Comment: i agree with rahul answer and [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43069835/1362442)
just go for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND email_sent = NULL` should be `AND email_sent IS NULL` using the `IS NULL` operator since you can't compare two `NULL` value using equality `=` operator